# how can I get only the SQL server logins, when we use Export-dbalogin

Tags: sql-server, migration, powershell, dbatools

when we run the export-dbalogin, it will will generate a script(.sql) file, which we will run the in the destination server, then the logins will be migrated, but this command will give both windows as well as SQL server logins. I only want SQL server logins.

I tried to use Get-dbalogin to generate a list of SQL server login and kept them in a variable, then I tried to pass that variable to the -login switch in Export-DbaLogin but it is not working.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [`Get-DbaLogin` source](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Get-DbaLogin.ps1#L34), the `-Type` parameter accepts a value of `'SQL'` to filter to only SQL Logins and exclude AD logins. You can pipe this directly into the `Export-DbaLogin` function like so...

```
Get-DbaLogin `
    -Type 'SQL' `
    -SqlInstance localhost | 
Export-DbaLogin `
    -FilePath 'foo.sql'
```

[image: powershell terminal showing sample code]

Note that some logins are excluded by default as shown in the warning feed.